# Meta unit for date in NPY_DATETIME gets overwrite in loop for NumPy C-API

Tags: python, c++, arrays, c, numpy

I'm trying to set units i.e NPY_FR_D for Date and NPY_FR_s for DateTime and Time using PyArray_DESCR which gets appended in a boost::python::list and returns to Python but the value of metadata->meta.base gets overwritten in a for loop and whatever value is being set last that is returned to python list.

As a result in Python, we get either one unit for all Datatype i.e datetime64[s] or datetime64[D]

According to NumPy C-API, PyArray_DESCR returns a borrowed reference to the dtype property of the array.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
for (unsigned c = 0; c < numFields; ++c)
{
    int typeNum;
    switch (m_typeVector[c])
    {
        case SRC::E_FieldType::E_FT_Date:
        case SRC::E_FieldType::E_FT_DateTime:
        {
            typeNum = NPY_DATETIME;
            break;
        }
        case SRC::E_FieldType::E_FT_Time:
        {
            typeNum = NPY_TIMEDELTA;
            break;
        }
        default:
            typeNum = NPY_NOTYPE;
            break;
    }
    SRC::Python::NumpyTransfer* colData = new SRC::Python::NumpyTransfer;
    if (typeNum != NPY_NOTYPE)
    {
        PyObject* npArr = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, typeNum);
        PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS((PyArrayObject*)npArr, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);
        auto descr = PyArray_DESCR(reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(npArr));
        auto metadata = reinterpret_cast<PyArray_DatetimeDTypeMetaData*>(descr->c_metadata);

        if (typeNum == NPY_DATETIME && m_typeVector[c] == SRC::E_FieldType::E_FT_DateTime)
        {
            metadata->meta.base = NPY_FR_s;
        }
        else if (typeNum == NPY_DATETIME && m_typeVector[c] == SRC::E_FieldType::E_FT_Date)
        {
            metadata->meta.base = NPY_FR_D;
        }
        else if (typeNum == NPY_TIMEDELTA && m_typeVector[c] == SRC::E_FieldType::E_FT_Time)
        {
            metadata->meta.base = NPY_FR_s;
        }
        colData->m_numpyArray = boost::python::handle<>(npArr);
        rawData.push_back(PyArray_DATA((PyArrayObject*)npArr));
        colData->m_isNumpy = true;

        ....

            colStorage.push_back(colData);
    }
}
```

I couldn't find anything to set a different meta for all, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer:
So finally I got the answer, PyArray_DescrNewFromType creates a new copy of the PyArray_Descr structure. I just have to create a descriptor first using typenum and and then create the array using PyObject* npArr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromDescr(1, dims, descr);

Comment: C & C++ are 2 different languages; which are you actually asking about?

Comment: The above code is in C++ but I'm using #include "ndarraytypes.h" for NumPy C-API.